# PDO securing select

Tags: php, pdo, while-loop, prepare

I am using this snippet for reading data from my database, this is what I tried:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM user");
$sth->execute();

while ($user = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    echo htmlspecialchars($user[1]);
}
```

I hope it cant be hacked using injection´s etc.

You think this is good enough, I mean I use prepared statements and

> htmlspecialchars()

Did i forget anything?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to  codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: i took a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1 but maybe i forgot something, so what u think about it?

Comment: `SELECT *` is enough open - resouce consumer and injection improver :D

Answer (score 1):

The section of you code that you've shown has no direct vulnerabilities because you're not evaluating any user input in your database query, therefore this is a non issue.

Answer (score 1):

`$dbh->prepare()` already does the escaping for you. There is a PDO function `PDO::quote()` to escape strings independently from the prepare method but as the doc says:

> If you are using this function to build SQL statements, you are
>   **strongly recommended to use PDO::prepare()** to prepare SQL statements
>   with bound parameters instead of using PDO::quote() to interpolate
>   user input into an SQL statement. Prepared statements with bound
>   parameters are not only **more portable, more convenient, immune to SQL
>   injection**, but are **often much faster** to execute than interpolated
>   queries, as both the server and client side can cache a compiled form
>   of the query.

The use of `htmlspecialchars()` is unnecessary, when you are printing content from the database. The point of escaping is to prevent [SQL Injections](http://www.php.net/manual/de/security.database.sql-injection.php) as you correctly noted. But these injections can only happen within your sql statement and only if (as Ohgodwhy mentioned) userinput from `$_POST` or `$_GET` or whaterver the user can manipulate is part of your query.